# How can I create a new file with a simple way in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

Currently, I know that I can create a new file with the following ways:

- `c` key in Neotree
- `SPC '` in shell layer, and use the `touch xxx` command

I am wondering whether there is a simple way (something like `SPC f xxx`) or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, you can use `SPC f f`, enter the name of the new file and then select the line starting with `[?]` (which is the default if no other file matches).

Note you can also use this to create files in non-existing subfolders, like `SPC f f my/sub/folder/file.txt RET`.

Comment: autocompletion is evil in this case, it tries to open file that somehow matches your new name

Comment: If you're using ivy, `C-M-j` (ivy-immediate-done) selects the current input instead of a match http://oremacs.com/swiper/. Helm probably has a similar feature.

Comment: I am using emacs binding and want to create new file inside directory open in neotree buffer using C-c C-n

Comment: For helm `M-SPC j` will enter transient state and go down one to the line starting with `[?]`. You can also use the down arrow. I find none of these ideal.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the standard vim like keybindings,

```
:e /path/to/file
```

works opens a file ( which doesn't have to exist before )

```
:x
```

saves the file and closes the buffer and

```
:w
```

saves without closing.